# catching keyboard interrupt

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a bash script that is executing a program in a loop and reading the output from the program.  I wish that when I hit control-c, it terminates the program as well as the script.

I tried this but does not seem to terminate the program.

```
control_c() {
   exit
}

while true ; do 

    trap control_c SIGINT

    my_command | while read line ; do
       echo $line 
       ...
    done
done
```

Can someone show me the correct way to accomplish what I have described?  Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

You can do something like this:

```
control_c() {
    kill $PID
    exit
}

trap control_c SIGINT

while true ; do 
   my_command | while read line ; do
   PID=$!
   echo $line 
   ...
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Try killing the program in your `control_c()` function, e.g.,

```
pkill my_command
```